# "on the link," "in the link," or "at the link"?

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, word-usage

Which is the correct usage:

1. Follow the instructions **on** the link mentioned above.
2. Follow the instructions **in** the link mentioned above.
3. Follow the instructions **at** the link mentioned above.

Comment: Neither. The "link" is just the thing you click to get to the page where the instructions are.

Comment: Use *at*. *The link* is used to mean *destination*: *Follow the instructions [that are] at the destination mentioned above.* But, really, don't refer someone back up the page; just link it again: _Follow the instructions at **My Awesome Place**._

Comment: Use "**in**": it means "within" and "link" is a synecdoche for "the page to which you will be linked by the hyperlink that has been given"

Comment: What about "Follow the instructions by following the link mentioned above."?

Comment: Why must you visit a golf course to read these instructions?

Comment: To some extent it matters if it's a direct link to instructions, or it's going to take you to a page that e.g. lets you download a PDF after filling in a form. So "at" or "via/using" might be more accurate depending.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, prepare to be dazzled:
When there's a single link, it's better to use "*at the link above*" because, exactly there, you'll find what you are looking for.

When there are multiple links and some might contain what you are looking for, maybe using "*(with)in the links above*" is a better choice. It's less specific than the previous case.

However, if you *can* find what you are looking for *at any of the links*, I'd use AT again since "*you can find what you are looking for at (any of) these links.*"

TL;DR:
I think it's all about how specific you want to be: you can't actually find anything within the link itself (OK, maybe some code, but we're abstracting some things here). You can find it at the link (at the address, as a pointer to something) or within the bunch of links (within those addresses, those pointers)...

At least my 5 cents.

Answer (score 2):

From the software point of view, a link is a program within which there are algorithmic routines to process entries made by the user. The instructions to the user about how to make the entries are not visible **on** the link, which is normally appears as something like this example: [Which is the better usage of the following phrase?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/549295/which-is-the-better-usage-of-the-following-phrase;) The instructions are revealed by the internal routines when the link is activated (or "*opened*" to reveal the instructions).

From this perspective I prefer "*Follow the instructions **in** the link mentioned above."*

Comment: See Google Ngrams ***in the link,at the link*** https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+link%2Cat+the+link&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20link%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20link%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20link%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20link%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your explanation. A link is not a program. Entries made by the user? It's a part of an interface. What can be in the link is... an URL of the linked document/page. So you can probably say that "in the link" is short for "in the linked document." But that doesn't work with "page." The text is rarely *in* the link. Sometimes it is next to the link but invisible. Sometimes it is on another page. You can probably say that there *might* be a miniprogram in the link, but isn't that too much to expect from a reader?

Comment: That is, you can in a way say that link is a program in the case where a link reveals (makes visible) a text that is near the link. If you say that link is a program when the link takes you to another page, that is even more far-fetched. "At" makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

It should be "through the link". Because you will be going to the page using the "link". It is not in the link itself, it is on the page. You are just using the link as the medium to go to the page. Therefore, you are getting to the page "through" the link.